# Fully remove PlayOnLinux and any files left behind

Tags: wine, uninstall, playonlinux, purge, software-uninstall

I recently installed PlayOnLinux with:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

But then decided that I wanted to remove it so I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge playonlinux
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And I thought that this would have removed all the files associated with PlayOnLinux, but I see that there is still a folder called `.PlayOnLinux` in my `~/` directory, so I will remove this too, but is there anything else which PlayOnLinux would have left behind that I can remove, or reset? And anyway, what is this hidden folder which it left behind in my home area?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The `.playonLinux` directory is where POL stores its virtual drives. (Where it runs the Windows programs) If you did not have WINE installed beforehand, you will also need to run `sudo apt-get purge wine`. If you are still suspicious you can search for "playonlinux" in the dash/Nautilus.

Comment: To answer the latter. The hidden folders in your home directory are local settings for the given program. When  uninstalling a program the settings folder stays if you don't manually delete it